Why is the sound of 'читаем' is 'chitaem', not 'chitayem'?
In Duolingo, I was asked what the sound of 'читаем' is.
I answered 'chitayem, but failed.
The correct answer was 'chitaem', which I don't understand.
Why is it?

My advice is to learn the IPA and use it when you study other languages' phonetics. The use of transliteration in DL is extremely counterproductive.

I googled and found a web page (there are probably many others) claiming that "читаем" is pronounced [t͡ɕɪˈtajɪm]. The [j] is the "y" that DL erroneously omits.

https://wikislovo.ru/phonetic/%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC

@DimitriVulis the problem are dialects. Russian got as many as English does because that's formed by a meld of local language traditions and prescription. E.g. there are people who outright pronounce or even stress  "oh" in  some word roots, like "корова". DL is very bad at dealing with dialects. I fail at DL's Russian too and my speech is Moscow Russian, i.e. it's largely standard. When I listen to someone  matching that one, it sounds like a Polish, East Ukraine or Chechen speaking, lol - alot of ioted vovels are softened.

Yes, https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Оканье and all that; and if you bother to dig up my 1988 M.A. thesis, "An Implementation of Liang's Algorithm for the Russian Language", I actually mention Russian regional variations in phonetics that I needed to address. Buy why would any RKI student want to learn anything but the contemporary standard Moscow pronunciation?  To impersonate a Volga boatman? :)

@swift Thanks, are you aware of any contemporary dialects where читаем sounds not like [...jɪm], but  rather [...ʲem],  [...əm] etc? (Volga boatmen reference:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KfsWoNpHg2s  )

@DimitriVulis What notation it is? Northern, maybe. Pomors. the mistake is likely is wrong notation or a mix-up. because after soft vovel "е" is [ɪ] ([ие]) in IPA notation (not /i/),  it isn't sound like one in English "girth". It's the middle vowel in "yield".

Wikipedia https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Еканье , citing sources, claims that "еканье was the main pronunciation norm of the Russian literary language in 19th century. Since the end of the 19th century, еканье was being replaced by иканье and is now almost completely replaced, but it is still an orthoepic norm. Еканье is one of the features of the old Petersburg pronunciation, but it is gradually disappearing from the speech of Petersburgers."

@DimitriVulis that one kind of supports what I said about it being northern, it's our analog of "Midland English". Note, that's just two people's opinion and these two are largely undisputed. Things is, the area where Russian is used is much larger than country itself and spreads outside of of one country,while the sources there limit it to  standartized, "metropolian" point of view. еканье is still orphoepic norm. иканье by area where it's used -Transcarpatia, Belarus, South Russia and Ukraine - is mainstream by numbers. Middle Asia actually got typical pronunciation with еканье.

There are different romanizations of Russian Cyrilic. And Duolingo could be using any such standard, or no standard at all – I couldn‘t find out. The question is, thus, more about whatever Duolingo is fabricating than Russian itself.
So, in other words Duolingo‘s options here are quite arbitrary (at least outside of Duolingo). I guess, the point here is that in the duolingo world „ye“ is used for a stressed cyrillic е. Since е in читаем is unstressed „chitayem“ would be wrong accordingly.
That being said, I don‘t deem using romanized Russian of great help for learning the pronunciation – quite the opposite –, and I wouldn‘t sink any time into it. Duolingo just makes you learn an arbitrary mapping from one script to another, which doesn‘t really work in the first place as there are sounds in Russian not existing in English and vice versa. It‘s like making a detour AND ending up at the wrong destination.

As far as I know Duolingo doesn't use humans for Russian but it uses a speech software and it makes many mistakes. Have you heard the pronunciation of theatre?

I‘ve never used DL myself to learn any language, since I deem it very inefficient in general. But at least from friends I know that the German and French courses have (or had) generated audio that sometimes produced wrong or weird pronunciations. So I could very well imagine that any course using this software will produce such slips.
